# System boots to initramfs with fsck recommendation

Tags: startup

[image: photo of screen showing initramfs prompt]

I cannot start my laptop, this keeps popping up. How do I go about it?

Comment: I would suggest doing what it tells you to do, ie. run a `fsck` manually. Boot *live* media & `fsck` your partitions for what looks like a Ubuntu 20.04 LTS system.  It's best if we're told everything & not making assumptions (it's safer if we're told).  Change out `fsck` to an appropriate command if your file-system varies to defaults...

Comment: @guiverc No need for a Ubuntu Live for this fsck. See my answer.

Comment: Please see my answer. If it's helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe @heynnema but on any *like*  issue I prefer to stop booting the drive(s) and boot *live* media so I can have a look from there, including checking drive health (SMART) etc which can be easier if the drive is not in use.  (*Anything unusual has me looking for issues wider than whatever presented or asked in this question*)..

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 3):

At the initramfs prompt, type: `fsck -f /dev/sda3`

When complete, type: `reboot`